# Calculate weighted mean point from array of 3D point.

Tags: 3d

I have a set of points whose positions are represented by 3D vectors.
Each point has the associated weight in range from 0 to 1. The sum of all weights doesn't equal to 1.

How should the weighted mean point be calculated from the whole set of points?

Comment: I don't understand "I have a set of points set by 3D vectors representing their positions." Do you mean something like "I have a set of points whose positions are represented by 3D vectors"?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is called normalization, and you simly divide each weight by the sum of all the weights:
$$w_i \rightarrow \frac{w_i}{\sum w_i}$$
You can easily verify that the sum of the new weights is now $1$.

The mean vector is given by the sum:
$${\bf{v}} = \sum w_i \bf{v}_i$$

Comment: Well, that is obvious. But that just makes the sum of weights equal to 1. But how to use these weights to calculate the weighted mean vector?

Comment: @BartoNaz - Edited my answer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Probably yes. I think this should be correct. Thank you.